# Including enum in JPA query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, enums

I have a class in the following form.

```
@Entity
public class Person{
    public enum SEX {
      MALE, FEMALE, OTHER
    }

    private String name;
    private SEX sex;
 }
```

And I have an interface class which extends the `JpaRepostory`. The enum doesn't work in the query. I am trying to using `Spring JPA` for fetchig the data.

```
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {


    @Query("SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE 
            "p.SEX = com.example.Person.Sex.MALE " +
            "AND p.name = :name")
    public List<Person> checkName(@Param("name") String name,);

}
```

I get the following exception

`Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path: 'com.example.Person.Sex.MALE'`

How can I fix it ?

Comment: or use a parameter and set it to an enum value

Comment: Your enum is named SEX, not Sex. Your sex attribute in Person is named sex, not SEX.

Comment: Please follow the Java naming conventions. It actually helps prevent mistakes.

Comment: How are you mapping sex column in entity class and what is database column type for sex .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're not respecting the case of your classes and attributes. It should be

```
p.sex = com.example.Person.SEX.MALE
```

Comment: what about in Hibernate 6? now it no longer works like this

Answer (score 1):

Beyond the case errors which have already been mentioned, there is another problem: your enum class is a nested class. And a third problem is that Hibernate seems to have problems with capitalized class names, i.e. you need to change the class name from `SEX` to `Sex`.

### Variant 1:

Define the enum as a top-level class in package `com.example`

```
package com.example;
public enum Sex {
    MALE, FEMALE, OTHER
}
```

and then you can access an enum value from the repository using e.g. `com.example.Sex.MALE`:

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE " + 
            "p.sex = com.example.Sex.MALE " +
            "AND p.name = :name")
    public List<Person> checkName(@Param("name") String name);

}
```

Surprisingly (a bug?) this will end up with an error if you change the name of the enum from `Sex` to `SEX` (while adjusting the name in the query obviously).

### Variant 2:

You could keep the definition of `Sex` as a nested class. The enum is then compiled into the class with the name `Person$Sex.class`. Simply use this name in the query string:

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    public enum Sex {
        MALE, FEMALE, OTHER
    }

    @Id @GeneratedValue long id;
    private String name;
    private Sex sex;
    
    public Person() {}
    public Person(String name, Sex sex) {
        this.name = name;
        this.sex = sex;
    }
}
```

The repository then needs to be written as

```
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE " + 
            "p.sex = com.example.Person$Sex.MALE " +
            "AND p.name = :name")
    public List<Person> checkName(@Param("name") String name);

}
```

Once again, if you change the name of the nested class fom `Sex` to `SEX` (also in the query string) then an exception with the text

```
Invalid path: 'com.example.Person$SEX.MALE' 
   [SELECT p FROM com.example.Person p WHERE p.sex = com.example.Person$SEX.MALE 
                                                             AND p.name = :name]
```

is thrown, although the generated byte code is stored in class `Person$SEX.class`.